# Get Scroll Position inside Relative Positioned <div> Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Is there any way to find out how much someone has scrolled when the content is in a container div with position:relative. I can only seem to get scroll position using JavaScript or JQuery when position is set to absolute, but this disrupts the site layout. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Can you post your html and script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't seem to have any problem in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQ69u/

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
#scrollable{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

or even in this one: http://jsfiddle.net/dQ69u/1/

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
#scrollable{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#000;
}
#scrollBox{
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think there are a few missing elements in my CSS that are causing the issue. It looks like I needed to define a height, for one. Thanks.